# Uniqueness of Inverse and Identity (Group Theory Abstract Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider addition modulo N relation $a \pmod n$ over all the integers for example.
We can easily prove that this is a group. Identity is any element which satisfies the following:

$$a \cdot e=a$$

In the given relation $a \pmod n$, we can have $0$ as identity. But $n, 2n$ and so on. These numbers will also satisfy the above condition.

Similarly we can have multiple inverses by just adding $n, 2n$ and so on..

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are the elements of your group?

Comment: Set of integers, or real numbers.

Comment: What is the operation? Your set is a group under addition but *not* multiplication (why not?).

Comment: user2277550, Please read the question. Let me know what part you didn't get. I have mentioned everything in my question.

Comment: Operation is Congruence modulo N. I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AvnishGaur "Congruence modulo N" is not a binary operation $G\times G\rightarrow G$ which you need for a group. "Addition modulo N" and "multiplication modulo N" are.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it to "Addition modulo N" from "Congruence modulo N"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are missing is that you're thinking of all of $\mathbb{Z}$ when in reality, you don't have that, you have the equivalence classes $[0],[1],[2],\ldots,[n-1]$. For each equivalence class we have 
$$[i]=\{kn+i:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
Which is a collection fo elements in $\mathbb{Z}$, however what you are dealing with is the quotient group for which each element, the congruence class $[i]$, is a collection of elements in the mother group, in our case $\mathbb{Z}$.

So $0,n,2n,\ldots$ do not represent different elements in your $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, but rather is different representation of the same element. Just like with rational numbers
$$\frac{p}{q}=\frac{jp}{jq}$$
Different representations, the same element.

Comment: Alright, that explains it. But what if I don't consider the equivalence classes, and take all the integers separately? I can't do that because they are basically the same numbers, is it so?

Comment: You can't do that because the group structure is on the equivalence classes as elements, not the individual elements themselves from the mother group.

Comment: What is Podulo in this context?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not understanding what you are trying to say, care to give an example to illustrate your idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45804/discussion-between-avnish-gaur-and-zelos-malum).